# Blacklisted on Facebook/Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, blacklist

When requesting the Facebook/Graph API with a Facebook App, I get the error `(#5) Unauthorized source IP address`. Searching the internet I found that adding the server's IP to the app's whitelist may work. But when I do that, I get the following error: `Uncaught OAuthException: This IP can't make requests for that application.`

The server has definitely only the IP address I added to the whitelist. Using another server with the same app works just fine. I suppose this is due to a bug in our application requesting the API too often with invalid keys (all from this very IP).

So, to me, this seems like something we need to contact Facebook for, so our IP gets unlisted. Somebody has a idea on how to do it?

Comment: Good luck getting Facebook to respond.  I had the same trouble a while ago.  I ended up moving the whole thing to a different domain.  They didn't respond at ALL, and I contacted them daily about it.  Nothin.

Answer (score 0):

First, access `canhazip.com` or `jsonip.com` from the server to make sure it has the public IP you think it does. Second, make sure that IP address is in "Server IP Whitelist" for the app's Settings > Advanced section in the Developer console (`https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[APP ID]/settings/advanced/`).

Comment: `canhasip.com` says the IP is blocked and refers to CloudFare security. I'm quite confident this is related to the Facebook issue.

`jsonip.com` verifies that the IP I thought was the correct one actually is correct.

I'll keep you posted and thank's for your answer!